# normality of residuals in a multiple regression hypothesis?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, multiple-regression

I am trying a multiple regression on a 25000 observations data base, each obs is representing the scores of a student in 7 subjects (Math, PC, SVT, Ar,Fr,EI,HG) plus a final exam (moy_exam2), don't worry the final exam moy_exam2 is not calculed in function of the 7 scores previously mentionned, so my objective is to explain the final exam variable using the 7 variables,
[image]
to that end I needed to make a test on the normality of residuals
of course the first thing to do in a regression is to verify the normality of the residuals, in my markdown file a try capturing them then use qqnorm to compare the observations in the DB with the theoritical values if the obs were normally distributed :

```
mod<-lm(moy_exam2~Math+PC+SVT+EI+Ar+Fr+HG,epltn)
e<-mod$residuals
qqnorm(e,epltn=TRUE,ylab="Quantiles observés",xlab="Quantiles théoriques")
```

the dots must be close to aligned , but I get this weird shape,
[image: weired shape]
here is the histogram of risiduals again it's not normal
[image]
and the fitted mod also confirms the problem of non normality of the residuals:
[image]

Also Predicted VS Actual gives me this :
[image]
I moved on to find the multiple regression model based on these variables, with an R squared of $R^2=0.9995$ and the model is :
$$Y = -0.012  + 0.230\times Math + 0.078 \times PC +0.077 \times SVT +0.077 \times EI +0.231   \times Ar+0.231  \times Fr+0.077  \times HG $$

is the residual problem a big problem ? is it suggesting my multiple regression is useless because the normality Hypothesis is not met ? what can I do to fix it ?
will the residuals problem affect the next step when I try to make predictions ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: This really belongs on CrossValidated, not StackOverflow, because the programming component is incidental. But while I'm here: Normality of residuals is only an important assumption for some purposes. Normality of residuals is not necessary for OLS to be BLUE, for example (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem). So I disagree with the premise that you should check this first, or that non-normality could make a regression "useless". It is a common misconception.

Comment: You have a huge number of 0's or nearly 0's.

Comment: What are your variables? What is `moy_exam2`, eg? What is `math`, etc? What do  you want to do with this model?

Comment: I will edit the post to answer your questions, thanks for the help

Comment: The tails of the distribution are the scientifically most interesting observations, because these are under- and overperforming during the final exam relative to their perfomance in class. If you can find additional variables explaining these, that would be incredibly useful. Logically this could be psychological issues, remedial classes, cheating, ...

Comment: Note that you are likely to have a severe issue with collinearity here.

Comment: yes, exacly, that is what I thought in the begining, for, the majority of students, the final exam cannot be explained in relation with their performance in class, that means we are having a lot of cheating and that goes both ways, also for the coliniarity issue I am about to see what its matrix is going to give me as results

Comment: It could be cheating, or it could be that exam is not measiring the same thing ...

Comment: Is it possible to make the data available somewhere? In my opinion, it makes perfect sense to have some relationship between performance in class and the final exam.

Comment: Most likely, there is something systemic in the data itself that is causing this problem. For example, if not all students have taken all 7 subjects and you are not treating those properly, it might explain the results. Suggest you show more data, because it is likely to then be obvious.

Answer (score -3):

Actually the Assumption of Normality is not concerned with the distribution of the residuals but with the distribution  of  sample  means  (across  independent  samples).
And according to the central limit theorem, one can expect the this normality to be given when your sample size is larger than 30.
So a regression can still be performed even if the residuals are not normally distributed.

However, looking at the distribution of residual is important to see how the model behaves. And in return you might decide that a differnt model might be better suited.
In your case qqplot looks so off that there must be something wrong with your data, and this could come from weirdly shaped distributions of your data.

Comment: but there is no problem with the data, I cant understand why the first and last parts are normal, but the middle almost all 0s ?

Comment: Plot the distribution of actual residuals ones. It appears that you predict a lot of individuals scores perfectly and many completely wrong

Comment: ok, you mean I should create a new database made only from the residual individuals, and plot it right ?

Comment: I think in SPSS you have the option to save the residuals in a new variable when carrying out a regression. Then I would just make a hsitorgam or

Comment: `hist(residuals(mod))` and `plot(residuals(mod) ~ fitted(mod))`.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a misunderstanding! Normality **is** about residuals. That the CLT can be used even without normality is another issue.

Comment: Ok, I added them in the post, but still it won't help , it looks not normal

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen yes I understand that these two issue are not identical -> but it was also asked whether the regression is now useless bc the normaility of the residuals is not met

Comment: @user2161721 Adjust the binwidth of the histogram. You should have way more bins.

Comment: Please then augment your answer making all this clear, and I will remove the downvote!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen CLT  is coliniarity u mean right ? I understand normality is about residuals so I will remove the part of the question where I was confused about it , thanks

Comment: @Roland I tried with the attribute break  , but the number of the bin ins always 3 ?! ```{r}
hist(residuals(mod), breaks =20 )

```

Comment: NO, sorry, CLT is central limit theorem!

Comment: yes of course, the CLT is not a problem, I understand that the situation is like this, my model predicts perfectly most of the values of the final exam of most of the students, exept the ones in  the tail and the head of the QQ plot above

Comment: @Janosch , I tried ploting predicted vs actual ,I edited the post, what do u think ?? thanks

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I improved the answer to be more clear on the destinction